# Iterate through all collections and remove them

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code:

```
exports.cleanDB = function() {
  return mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();
};
```

Since that is malpractice, I want to iterate through all collections and want to call

```
mongoose.connection.db.DateTime.remove();
```

on every one it.

Can somebody help me to create the code together with that return statement?

On another part of the app similar code where I don't know how to rewrite:

```
  exports.cleanDB = function*(req) {

    yield mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();
```

Comment: *"Since that is malpractice"* -- Is it? Who says? Is there some problem with this other than there is not presently anything ( built in method triggered that is ) to support adding collation options to a collection or similar? So why is it you think you cannot do that?

Comment: Dropping the databases like that results in duplicate key errors (11000) in our case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really don't see what's wrong with dropping the database. But if you really must then you can just loop the registered models and do a `.remove()`.

For instance:

```
// Just similating an async wrapper
(async function() { 

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    // Loop all registered models
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove())
    )

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  }

})()
```

Or plain promises:

```
mongoose.connect(uri,options).then( conn => {

  Promise.all(
    Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove())
  ).then( () => /* something */ )

})
```

You can even do [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) if you don't have support for [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
mongoose.connect(uri,options).then( conn => {

  Promise.all(
    Object.keys(conn.models).map(k => conn.models[k].remove())
  ).then( () => /* something */ )

})
```

Or if you really must, then dig into the database level and wipe all the collections using the [`.collections()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#collections) method from `Db`

```
(async function() { 

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    // Get every collection in an array
    await Promise.all(
      (await conn.db.collections()).map( c => c.remove() )
    );

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  }

})()
```

Or plain promises:

```
mongoose.connect(uri,options).then( conn => {

  conn.db.collections()
    .then( collections => Promise.all( 
      collections.map( c => c.remove() )
    )
    .then( () => /* something */ )

})
```

And that would not matter if the model was registered or not.

So it really depends on which approach you would rather take, and if you already have code that should have processed to load and register each model then using the registered models should be sufficient. Otherwise using the direct driver method to grab references to all collections presently in the database makes sure that even if the model has not yet been registered, then it's collection still has all content removed.

Note that [`Db.collections()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#collections) is basically a wrapped version of the output from [`Db.listCollections()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#listCollections) which is actually returning [`Collection`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html) objects instead of just the 'names'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. As said, dropping DB many often during testing results in duplicate key errors. This is why I want to try this. How would you wrap the last solution into a yield?